# $C^1(\mathbb{R}) \subset D \subset \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $D$ be the set of all differentiable functions on $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$, and let $C^1(\mathbb{R})$ be the set of all functions defined on the real line that have continuous derivative. How can I show that $C^1(\mathbb{R}) \subset D \subset \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$? Thank you!

See the comment below in context [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356572/part-ii-an-attested-subspace-of-mathbbr-mathbbr/356581?noredirect=1#356581). I'm trying to make this proof as sound as I can. Maybe getting help like this is not constructive. What do you think?

"I used to teach honors calculus. The limit part is not sufficient if you want to go that way; you've only proved that the function is differentiator, not that it's continuous. If you really want to go that way, you could use your technique to show that differentiable functions are a subspace of all functions, and then show that C1 functions are a subspace of differentiable functions. That would be the easiest thing in my opinion."

Comment: Unwind the definitions of differentiability at a point and continuity at a point.

Comment: What do this have to do with set theory?

Comment: I'm meaning $\subset$ to mean "subspace of."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$, then, by definition, $f$ is a continuously differentiable function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.
In particular, $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$, so $f\in D$.
This shows that $C^1(\mathbb{R}) \subset D$.

If $g\in D$, then, again by definition, $f$ is a differentiable function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.
In particular, $f$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, so $f\in\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$.
This shows that $D \subset \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$.

**Edit.** (*thanks to Andreas Blass*)

To show strict inclusions (i.e., that $C^1(\mathbb{R})\subsetneq D$ and $D\subsetneq\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$), you need to find a function $f\in D$ whose derivative is not continuous everywhere, as well as a function $g\in\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ which is not differentiable everywhere.
An example of such an $f$ is $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
0, & \text{if $x = 0$,} \\
x^2 \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right), & \text{if $x \neq 0$}.
\end{cases}
$$
This function is differentiable everywhere, but its derivative is not continuous at $0$.
An example of a function $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ which is not differentiable everywhere is, for example, $g(x)=|x|$, which fails to be differentiable at $0$.

Comment: I conjecture that Trancot is using $\subset$ to mean $\subsetneq$ rather than $\subseteq$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: Ah, thank you! That may very well be the case.

Comment: What do each mean? I've made a mistake? Where?

Comment: Some mathematicians use the symbol "$\subset$" to mean "$\subseteq$", while others use it to mean "$\subsetneq$". There is no universal agreement about which symbol to use for strict set inclusion.

Comment: Intuitively, what do each mean to you in particular?

Comment: @Trancot: The expression "$A \subsetneq B$" usually means that for every $x\in A$, it is true that $x \in B$, but there also exists a $y\in B$ such that $y\notin A$. This means that every element of $A$ is contained inside $B$, but $A$ does not contain all the elements of $B$. In particular, $A \neq B$. The expression "$A\subseteq B$" usually only means that for every $x\in A$, it is true that $x \in B$. This means that every element of $A$ is contained inside $B$, but it also includes the case that $A = B$.

Comment: Check your $f$s and $g$s.

Comment: So the one with the slash means that $A$ is smaller than $B$?

Comment: @ArtemMavrin What is "strict inclusion"?

Comment: @ArtemMavrin Do you have some literature on what you were referring to about containment notation?

Comment: First comment: What do you mean? Check what? Second comment: No, if $A$ and $B$ are two infinite sets, then it is possible that $A\subsetneq B$, but $A$ and $B$ have the same cardinality (consider $A=2\mathbb{Z}$ and $B=\mathbb{Z}$). Third comment: By strict inclusion, I mean "$\subsetneq$". Fourth comment: I can't think of a book that makes a big deal about this notation, and it greatly varies between books. Usually you can check an introductory section of a book and the author will state his or her personal notation conventions.